# Efficient algorithm to return all rectangles on a surface

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

One critical piece of code on my application involves enumerating all rectangles on a 2-D surface. The rectangles do not intersect each other and I must be able to enumerate all rectangles within a given rectangular boundary.

I already have a function to return the rectangle for a given coordinate, if it exists

```
GetRectangle( int row, int col )
```

Here is how I would call the resulting code.

```
foreach( var rect in GetRectangles( row, col, rowCount, colCount ) ) {
   //..  my processing code here
}
```

Obviously, I could call the function `GetRectangle()` for each of the points in the surface. I can also skip the width of the rectangle that was returned from the previous call as I know that they do not intersect. But, this is still not efficient enough.

Are you aware of such an algorithm?

UPDATE: The surface is not necessarily covered by rectangles but it can be for some special cases. So, the function `GetRectangle( int row, int col )` might return null.

Think of the surface as a bitmap filled with random rectangles (which don't intersect). The task is to return all rectangles on that surface that falls within (i.e. intersects) a given frame. Hope this will clarify the question.

Thanks

Comment: Can the rectangles be rotated? edit: Ok, this is already implicitly answered, sorry.

Comment: Hi Kemal, could you be a bit more descriptive? Perhaps provide a diagram of what you mean by enumerating all rectangles on a 2D surface?

Comment: Why can't you keep track of the rectangles as they are added to the surface?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For best results, organize your collection of rectangles into a [spatial lookup structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index). In this case it sounds as though a [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) would be a good bet. But if you can't do that, and `GetRectangle` is all you've got, then here is what I'd do:

The plan is to maintain a list of integers *x*<sub>*j*</sub> for 0 ≤ *j* < `rowCount`, where *x*<sub>*j*</sub> is the leftmost point on row *j* for which I have not yet found a rectangle covering it.

1. Start by initializing *x*<sub>*j*</sub> := 0 for all *j*.
2. If *x*<sub>*j*</sub> = `colCount` for all *j*, we are done. Stop.
3. Let *J* = min(*j* | *x*<sub>*j*</sub> = min(*x*<sub>*i*</sub>)). Then *x*<sub>*J*</sub> is the topmost leftmost point that I have not yet found a rectangle that covers it.
4. Call `GetRectangle`(*x*<sub>*J*</sub>, *J*). If this does not return a rectangle, then the point is uncovered. Set *x*<sub>*J*</sub> := *x*<sub>*J*</sub> + 1 and go to step 2.
5. Otherwise, we have a rectangle with top left corner at (*x*<sub>*J*</sub>, *J*). Call its width *w* and height *h*. For *J* ≤ *j* < *J* + *h*, set *x*<sub>*j*</sub> := *x*<sub>*j*</sub> + *w*. Go to step 2.

Here's an example run of this algorithm. The list of *x*<sub>*j*</sub> is shown by the numbers at the left, with the topmost leftmost highlighted in bold. The orange rectangle is the one that's discovered at that step of the algorithm.

[image: The algorithm finds seven rectangles in seven steps]

For efficient discovery of the minimum at step 3, you might want to keep the list of *x*<sub>*j*</sub> in a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: Hi Gareth, I am afraid, your example run was not pasted into your answer correctly. Could you please re-do the paste. Thank you